# On CentOS Linux 7.4, cannot install the R package "httpuv"

Tags: r, centos

I am currently using CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 (Core). I have tried to install the package `httpuv` in `R` through various methods to no avail. It always ends with the error:

```
  CC       src/unix/libuv_la-procfs-exepath.lo
  CC       src/unix/libuv_la-proctitle.lo
  CC       src/unix/libuv_la-sysinfo-loadavg.lo
  CC       src/unix/libuv_la-sysinfo-memory.lo
  CCLD     libuv.la
libtool:   error: require no space between '-L' and '-L/n/helmod/apps/centos7/Core/pcre/8.37-fasrc02/lib'
make[1]: *** [libuv.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/Rtmp5Dj7hL/R.INSTALL5c046d96dc92/httpuv/src/libuv'
make: *** [libuv/.libs/libuv.a] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘httpuv’
```

Does anyone have any thought as to what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: `libuv.la` is a small text file, 928B https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ulaunamtf6ji8p/libuv.la?dl=0 .... The file is not included in the CentOS7 `libuv-devel` : Copy the file to `/usr/lib64/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answer is partially correct in that it identifies `libuv` as the missing dependency.

In CentOS 7 you can add this with `yum install libuv-devel`, then attempt to install the package again with `install.packages("httpuv")` and provided that was your only issue, it should compile correctly.

Comment: libuv is not available in default CentOS 7 packages, so I needed to enable first the EPEL repository: `yum install epel-release`

Comment: or do this `yum --enablerepo=epel install libuv-devel`

Answer (score 1):

The error says that there is a library error in libuv.la.
The cc and CCLD commands show that this is a compilation error - very likely from gcc thrown when trying to compile libuv.la.

In ubuntu linux, I would look in such cases:

```
$ apt search httpuv
# which gives:
# r-cran-httpuv
```

R packages with mostly need other system dependencies (libraries outside of R etc) mostly have a package in the apt repository.

Then you do simply:

```
$ sudo apt install r-cran-httpuv
```

And then every dependency problems are resolved (though it might be that R asks you to update/upgrade your package after the installation - which sometimes works but sometimes not).

I was looking if CentOS can use `apt`:
https://everyday-tech.com/apt-get-on-centos/

Another possibility for you would be to use conda which is great to solve such dependency problems. People have then similar to apt prepared for you conda-packages which provide all package dependencies.

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge r-httpuv
```

If you don't know conda, I highly recommend you this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJC6ldI3hWk (from Corey Schafer who gives great - mainly Python - tutorials).